# How to parse this JSON url with Authorization to HTML table/ list with php

Tags: php, html, json, xml

I am trying to get this JSON-data from here: https://gw.bilinfo.net/listingapi/api/export

They have a 'how to sheet' here: https://developer.bilinfo.net/content/Bilinfo_XML_API.pdf

I can connect with Authorization and can get the raw JSON, but I can't make a table with the data.

This is my code so far:

```
    <?php
$url = 'https://gw.bilinfo.net/listingapi/api/export';

// provide your username and password here
$auth = base64_encode("demo:ocfB6XzF73");

// create HTTP context with basic auth
$context = stream_context_create([
    'http' => ['header' => "Authorization: Basic $auth"]
]);

// query for data
$data = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
$escaped = json_encode($data);

/*Initializing temp variable to design table dynamically*/
$temp = "<table>";

/*Defining table Column headers depending upon JSON records*/
$temp .= "<tr><th>Bilmodel</th>";
$temp .= "<th>Motor</th>";
$temp .= "<th>Drivmiddel</th></tr>";

/*Dynamically generating rows & columns*/
for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($escaped["Vehicles"]); $i++) {
    $temp .= "<tr>";
    $temp .= "<td>" . $escaped["Vehicles"][$i]["Model"] . "</td>";
    $temp .= "<td>" . $escaped["Vehicles"][$i]["Motor"] . "</td>";
    $temp .= "<td>" . $escaped["Vehicles"][$i]["Propellant"] . "</td>";
    $temp .= "</tr>";
}

/*End tag of table*/
$temp .= "</table>";

/*Printing temp variable which holds table*/
echo $temp;
?>
```

Comment: How to access the underling arrays with pictures and so on. How to reach them?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Solution 1.***
JSON_FORCE_OBJECT on encoding PHP array value, then each array element will be added to an index even though if input array doesn’t have any index.

So you can just use

```
$escaped = json_encode($data, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

and your code will print the table.

***Solution 2.***
Currently `json_encode`  converting data to StdObject in which you can read data using an arrow symbol. So printing data in your table just use foreach function reading Vehicles object with the arrow symbol.

```
 /*Dynamically generating rows & columns*/
    foreach ($escaped->Vehicles as $vehicle){
        $temp .= "<tr>";
        $temp .= "<td>" . $vehicle->Model . "</td>";
        $temp .= "<td>" . $vehicle->Motor . "</td>";
        $temp .= "<td>" . $vehicle->Propellant . "</td>";
        $temp .= "</tr>";
    }
```

Comment: Wow, this is wild - It works like a charm c,) - thank you so much!

Comment: @MartinWichmand you just need to remove for loop then add the above foreach. Also, make sure to do json_encode without JSON_FORCE_OBJECT as you did previously . like this json_encode(data); then foreach

Comment: thanks it works like it should... Thank you so much!